# Raspberry Pi 4: exchange power LED with activity LED

Tags: pi-4, led, board-leds, activity-led

the default situation with the two LEDs on my Raspberry Pi 4 is as such:

[situation now]

```
Green LED: read and write activity of my SD card
Red LED: Power
```

I would like to change the the LEDs to:

[desired situation]

```
Green LED: Power 
Red LED: Read and write activity of my SD card
```

How would I accomplish this swap of the LED indicators?

Thanks in advance for a hint.

Comment: Is the color more important, or the location?  Are you willing/able to de-solder and re-solder the LEDs themselves?

Comment: It is the colour and what it indicates. The position is ok. therefor a software solution is needed. Thanks for the clarification question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### QUESTION - How to change LED function:

> Green LED: Power (indicate power is applied)
> Red LED: (indicate) Read and write activity of my SD card

### ANSWER:

Add the following lines to your `/boot/config.txt` file:

```
dtparam=act_led_trigger=default-on 
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=mmc0
```

Before adding these lines, you should ***verify*** that there are no other `dtparam` statements in `/boot/config.txt` that address `act_led_trigger` or `pwr_led_trigger`. Also verify that there are no `dtoverlay=act-led` statements.

After saving the edited `/boot/config.txt` file, exit your editor & reboot your system.